# How to perform series expansions of special functions with special arguments?

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

I want to determine the series expansion of `PolyLog[n,z]` for integer but arbitrary `n` near `z=1`. If I plug in, for instance, `Series[PolyLog[n,z],{z,1,10}]` Mathematica returns the series expansion for generic non-integer `n`. Using the code `Assuming[Element[n,Integers],Series[PolyLog[n,z],{z,1,10}]]` also does not work. Is there anyway I can determine this special series expansion in Mathematica for arbitrary, but integer `n`?

Comment: Try using that assumption with `Simplify` perhaps?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer - I did. Doesn't work.